# Algorithm to find faster the suitable prefix for each phone number in log file?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, search, logfile

There is a csv file including the list of prefixes to categorise the phone numbers base on that. This is an example of prefixes.csv. This file have near to 2000 row.

```
3511891,PORTUGAL-MOBILE (VODAFONE)
3511693,PORTUGAL-MOBILE (OPTIMUS)
3511691,PORTUGAL-MOBILE (VODAFONE)
34,SPAIN-FIXED
3469400,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
3469310,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
3469279,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
3469278,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
3469277,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
3469276,SPAIN-MOBILE (MVNO)
34673,SPAIN-MOBILE (VODAFONE)
243820000006,CONGO DEMOCARTIC REPUBLIC-SPECIAL SERVICES
243820000005,CONGO DEMOCARTIC REPUBLIC-SPECIAL SERVICES
243820000004,CONGO DEMOCARTIC REPUBLIC-SPECIAL SERVICES
88213200361,EMSAT-SPECIAL SERVICES
67518497899,PAPUA NEW GUINEA-SPECIAL SERVICES
56751975883,CHILE-SPECIAL SERVICES
56751975334,CHILE-SPECIAL SERVICES
56731974707,CHILE-SPECIAL SERVICES
```

On the other hand, there is an huge log file including thousand of lines. This is the format of the log:

```
2015-11-01T00:00:17.735616+00:00 x1ee energysrvpol[15690]: INFO consume_processor: user:<<"dbdiayhg">> callee_num:<<"34673809195">> sid:<<"A1003unjhjhvhgfgvhbghgujhj02">> credits:-0.5000000000000001 result:ok provider:ooioutisrt.ym.ms
```

So, I have to extract the phone number after `callee_num`, and then compare it with all the prefixes , digit by digit, in order to discover what is the country code for the related number came after `callee_num`. In this example the phone number is `34673809195`, so extract this number, go to the **prefixes.csv** and check it row by row for the suitable prefix.

```
1)first time '3' from 34673xxxx
2)then 4
3) then 6
4) then 7
....
```

and all this process have to be repeated for each row of the **prefixes.csv**, and finally in this row `34673,SPAIN-MOBILE (VODAFONE)`, the number is matches. Imagine that the number instead of `34673` is `34670`, and after checking all the rows , there is not any match with this number, so it should possible to keep the last matches of **prefixes.csv** which is `34` and return the `SPAIN-FIX`.

**I would like to know what is the best algorithm to doing these processes in the minimum time. If I need to order the prefix before or I use only dictionary for that? How can I manage everything in order to have the efficient code? how should be worked the search algorithm? If the recursive function is the good idea for that or  not? or if there are some library in python that it is implemented good please recommend it.**

Thank you for providing any solution.

Comment: If you only have to process one log file, or if you can process them all at once, just using merge sort with a customized merge step can do the trick, without any extra data structures. Otherwise, or if you need linear time, you should use a trie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [prefix tree (Trie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure.

During scanning the tree, always remember the last best result (remember 34, while checking 34*** nodes)

There are many implementations of tries in Python

Comment: in some condition, like example above, the best result is `34673`  and not 34. Do u mean that this algorithm try to find the longest string which is matched with the phone number? What can be a parameter, I mean is better i pass all the prefixes.csv as dictionary or as list to the `start-with-prefix` in Trie library?

Comment: What is the best implementation for this algorithm in python @MBo

Comment: I don't use Python, but I heard that my colleague chose between datrie and marisa-trie some years ago.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand you problem, algorithm should find the longest matching string (and change best candidate from 34 to 34673).